# How do I add the hyphen in the for loop

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm a beginner in java and am writing a program and I want the output of what the user enters in for the String variable, wordEntered, to have a hyphen in to separate the letters but reduces the number of characters after each line.
Ex. wordEntered = "Baby";

Desired output:

```
B-a-b-y
 B-a-b
  B-a
   B
```

Currently, this is what my code looks like,

```
for (int i =0 ; i<wordEntered.length(); i++) {

        if (i < wordEntered.length()-1) 
            System.out.print(wordEntered.charAt (i) +"-");
        else
            System.out.println(wordEntered.charAt (i));
    }
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and can't even come close. Please help me.

Comment: Instead of printing the word, you can change the word to be "B-a-b-y" and then remove two letters from the end each time you print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a nested for loop to do this:

```
for (int j = wordEntered.length(); j > 0; j--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        if (i < j - 1)
            System.out.print(wordEntered.charAt(i) + "-");
        else
            System.out.println(wordEntered.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.print(StringUtils.repeat(" ", wordEntered.length() - j + 1));
}
```

Notice the outside loop goes from length of the word to 0. Also, I have used `StringUtils.repeat`. If you cannot use that then you can write a simple loop to print that many spaces.

Comment: that adds spaces on an extra line with no text

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        String wordEntered = "BABY";
        int nb_spaces = 0;

        while (wordEntered.length() > 0){
            // printing spaces
            for (int i =0 ; i<nb_spaces; i++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            nb_spaces += 1;

            // your loop 
            for (int i =0 ; i<wordEntered.length(); i++)
                if (i < wordEntered.length()-1) 
                    System.out.print(wordEntered.charAt (i) +"-");
                else
                    System.out.println(wordEntered.charAt (i));

            // removing last character
            wordEntered = wordEntered.substring(0, wordEntered.length()-1);
        }
    }
}
```